# micronaut controller returning empty json in nativeimage

Tags: micronaut, graalvm

I have a controller in micronaut

```java
package com.mascix.controller;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;

import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;

@Controller("/hello")
public class GreetController {
    @Get
    public Response hello() {
        return Response.ok(new ApplicationInfo("micronaut", LocalDate.now().getYear())).build();
    }
}

@Introspected
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
class ApplicationInfo {
    public ApplicationInfo(String string, int year) {
        this.name = string;
        this.releaseYear = year;
    }

    String name;
    int releaseYear;
}
```

which is working fine when I ran from jar and response is

```json
{"name":"micronaut","releaseYear":2022}
```

when I build the project with graalvm, it return empty json

```json
{}
```

you can see the whole code [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/test-microservice-frameworks/blob/main/micronaut/src/main/java/com/mascix/controller/GreetController.java). there is no error or warning in logs. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use @ReflectiveAccess for ApplicationInfo.

```java
package com.mascix.controller;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;

import io.micronaut.core.annotation.ReflectiveAccess;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;

@Controller("/hello")
public class GreetController {
    @Get
    public Response hello() {
        return Response.ok(new ApplicationInfo("micronaut", LocalDate.now().getYear())).build();
    }
}

@ReflectiveAccess
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
class ApplicationInfo {
    public ApplicationInfo(String string, int year) {
        this.name = string;
        this.releaseYear = year;
    }

    String name;
    int releaseYear;
}
```

And in order to this annotation work I needed to add micronaut-graal to annotationProcessorPaths/path in pom.

```xml
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
          <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->
          <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-graal</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=com.mascix</arg>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=demo</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

[see git log](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/test-microservice-frameworks/commit/b6894fed1e25c651e4e9f2c614ce7bde546856e3) and [more details](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#_understanding_micronaut_and_graalvm)

Comment: well done this worked for me, I had to add @ReflectiveAccess to the classes, in the native image build. I am using also the same framework to build native apps. I was stuck for 4 hrs until I found this, debugging native apps is a nightmare, its a terrible experience, no wonder native or Graal VM is not yet that popular, I had to build every time to check if it works, imagine having to build a whole application just later learn that you have a tone of run-time errors that you have to investigate until you're worn out. Graalvm should attempt to make the dev experience work better.

Comment: install the latest graal vm 22.2 which is building faster then before. and they just released the debugger with jetbrains check https://twitter.com/graalvm/status/1537851767320371204?s=20&t=twafQxVVOjVzbN1RVbFPNA